# how much security does the iPhone factory reset provide

Tags: data-leakage, data-recovery

when you factory reset an iphone is all the data on the device encrypted? as iphone uses nand/ is the data in the spare space also encrypted? by spare space i mean the worn out sectors. i'd also like to ask do file shredders do anything secure any deleted data.

Comment: why would it encrypt the data?

Comment: I think the question you want to ask is "what happens to the data after a factory reset and is it recoverable?" Asking if the data is encrypted is an awfully specific technical detail.

Comment: According to Apple, the data is deleted, not encrypted: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201252

Answer (score 1):

The data on the Iphone is deleted not encrypted as Schroeder mentioned in the comments: support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201252

File shredders write over the occupied space with zeros, though doing this on anything other than a spin drive is not recommended as it diminishes the life of the drive and some drives have smart tech which will just make this method infeasible. (shredders normally go over the space x amount of times)

I will suggest however if you want a way to ensure your data is gone I normally encrypted my device with a crazy long unthinkable password, factory reset and then encrypt again! without saving the keys and/or back up keys and re-encrypting over the deleted encrypted space. This should** keep your data safe.

Answer (score 0):

All data on an iPhone is encrypted by default.  When you do a factory reset the decryption key is discarded so the data is unretrievable:

> Felons wanting to best forensic investigators need only perform a
>   factory reset of all current model iPhones, say forensic security
>   experts.
>
> Apple's decision to encrypt data on the iPhone is responsible for this
>   state of affairs because a factory reset erases the decryption key
>   required to reveal the handset's contents, according to Jason Solomon,
>   a forensics investigator with Sydney-based Klein and Co.

https://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/05/01/thanks_for_nothing_apple_say_forensic_security_chaps/